# Como misturar um array em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array

No PHP, quando preciso misturar um array, utilizo a função `shuffle`.

Assim:

```
$a = array('@wallacemaxters', '@rray', '@CiganoMorrisonMendez');

shuffle($a);

print_r($a);
```

saida:

```
Array
(
    [0] => @CiganoMorrisonMendez
    [1] => @wallacemaxters
    [2] => @rray
)
```

Da mesma forma, preciso misturar um array em JavaScript. Porém não encontrei um método de `Array` que fizesse isso.

Como posso misturar um `Array` em JavaScript?

Comment: Não existe uma função nativa para isso em js? O.o

Comment: Não, foi por isso que perguntei

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Curioso ninguém ter mencionado o [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), que talvez seja o algoritmo mais clássico para permutar um set finito. O mais interessante é o fato de todos os possíveis retornos do algoritmo serem igualmente prováveis (em inglês, o termo para isso é *unbiased*).

[Aqui](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/) você pode ler um artigo interessante que mostra como construir esse algoritmo, desde o pseudo-código até um resultado de complexidade *O(n)* (você pode ler mais sobre complexidade [aqui](https://web.archive.org/web/20160315100615/http://www.inf.ufsc.br:80/%7Eine5384-hp/estrut07.html) - [outro link](https://www.ime.usp.br/%7Esong/mac5710/slides/01complex.pdf) ).

Para os **TL;DR**, a implementação final do algoritmo é

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var m = array.length, t, i;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle…
  while (m) {

    // Pick a remaining element…
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

    // And swap it with the current element.
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }

  return array;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Você pode fazer assim:

```js
function shuffle(o) {
  for (var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
  return o;
}

var myArray = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
console.info(shuffle(myArray));
```

Encontrei em [jsfromhell](http://jsfromhell.com/array/shuffle)

Answer (score 2):

Usando como [referência o underscorejs.com](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-39):

```js
Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
  var set = this;
  var length = set.length;
  var shuffled = Array(length);
  for (var index = 0, rand; index < length; index++) {
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (index - 1));
    if (rand !== index) shuffled[index] = shuffled[rand];
    shuffled[rand] = set[index];
  }
  return shuffled;
};


ary = ['@wallacemaxters', '@rray', '@CiganoMorrisonMendez'];
console.log(ary.sfuffle());
```

Comment: Nesse caso específico, dependeriamos do `undescore.js`. Obrigado, pois utilizo `undescore` em todos meus projetos :)

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando a resposta do @GabrielRodrigues, consegui chegar a um resultado, utilizando a função `sort`.

Assim:

```
a = ['@wallace', '@rray', '@cigano']

a.sort(function (a, b){ 
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
});

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fala galera, queria compartilhar com vocês uma das infinitas soluções =)

```
function shuffleArray(array = ["banana", "ovo", "salsicha", "goiaba", "chocolate"]) {
    const newArray = [];
    let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
    let count = 1;
    newArray.push(array[number]);

    while (count < array.length) {
        const newNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
        if (!newArray.includes(array[newNumber])) {
            count++;
            number = newNumber;
            newArray.push(array[number]);
        }
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Você pode utilizar esta solução também

```
shuffleArray(arr){
    let newArray = [];
    if(arr.length >= 2){
        while(newArray.length < arr.length){
            const rndIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr.length));
            if (newArray.indexOf(arr[rndIndex]) === -1) newArray.push(arr[rndIndex])
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Basicamente criamos uma comparação no loop while, verificando se um item existe no array, se não existir, damos um push, se ele existir tentamos mais um item aleatório do array, fazendo com que "embaralhe" o array de forma aleatória, mas por se tratar de um loop while de tentativa e erro eu usaria apenas para arrays que não tenham um tamanho muito grande.