# Como eu posso gerar numeros aleatorios sem repetição?

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho esse código pra gerar um numero aleatório entre 0 e 10, mas as vezes ele não acha o número entre 10.

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    var buscar = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
    if(buscar == caixaDoNumero.value) {
        alert("O segredo e: " + segredo); 
        break;
    }
}
```

Sem aumentar o tamanho do for.

Comment: Pode ser isso também http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94646/101