# Como escolher um elemento aleatório de array em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array

Já sei como [embaralhar um array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94646/69296), mas como faço para escolher um elemento aleatório de arrays?

```
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

Como faço para escolher um elemento qualquer de `arr`?

Comment: Acabei postando porque acho algo interessante e ainda não tem no site. Se a pessoa quiser justificar o -1 ficaria feliz em saber. :)

Comment: +1 essas iniciativas são boas pra comunidade e ainda tem gente que negativa.... vai entender.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta escolher um índice dentro dos limites do array para depois indexá-lo:

```
// Escolhendo o índice aleatório para o array `arr`:
const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);

// Indexando o elemento aleatório de `arr` a partir do índice:
const randomElement = arr[randomIndex];
```

Ou, em uma única linha:

```
const randomElement = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
```

Isso funciona garantidamente para qualquer elemento de `arr` (não importando o comprimento do array) uma vez que a função `Math.random` sempre retorna um número entre 0 inclusivo e 1 exclusivo, de modo que a função `Math.floor` sempre arredonda para baixo o produto, o que sempre resulta em um índice válido do array.

Por exemplo:

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const randomElement = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];

console.log(randomElement);
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma sugestão feita pelo [@K-Gun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23976260/1518921)  seria usar o operador bitwise `~` (**NOT**) duas vezes para se aproximar do inteiro, por exemplo:

```js
let value = 5;

console.log(value);   // 0000000000000101
console.log(~value);  // 1111111111111010
console.log(~~value); // 0000000000000101

value = 5.5;

console.log(value);   // 0000000000000101.1
console.log(~value);  // 1111111111111010
console.log(~~value); // 0000000000000101
```

Ou você também pode usar o bitwise `|` (**OR**) com o valor `0`, exemplo:

```js
let value = 5.6;

console.log(value | 0);
```

Exemplo de uso:

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const result1 = arr[~~(Math.random() * arr.length)];
const result2 = arr[Math.random() * arr.length | 0];

console.log('Resultado com ~~:', result1, 'Resultado com "| 0":', result2);
```

Usar Bitwise nesse caso foi 4% a 12% (aproximadamente) mais rápido que usar `Math.floor()` (depende do motor usado, aparentemente no V8 o `Math.floor` foi um pouco mais eficiente que em outros motores).

Se o objetivo é pegar um valor apenas não vai notar diferença, mas se o objetivo for obter diversos valores aleatórios, você pode ter uma pequena vantagem de tempo usando bitwise.

Veja o teste online para comparar a performance: https://jsbench.me/jcko4lx25k/1

Com navegadores os resultados as vezes variam um pouco, então criei um script para rodar em NodeJS com a lib

Teve o seguinte resultado:

```
C:\Users\inphinitphp\brcontainer\benchjs>node index.js
<testMathFloor> x 70,626,567 ops/sec ±4.74% (83 runs sampled)
<testNotBitwise> x 85,974,804 ops/sec ±1.45% (90 runs sampled)
<testOrBitwise> x 83,772,645 ops/sec ±1.84% (88 runs sampled)
Fastest is <testNotBitwise>,<testOrBitwise>
```

Sendo `~~` e `| 0` os mais rápidos, segue o código fonte para testes:

```
var Benchmark = require('benchmark');

var suite = new Benchmark.Suite;

const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

suite
.add('<testMathFloor>', testMathFloor)
.add('<testNotBitwise>', testNotBitwise)
.add('<testOrBitwise>', testOrBitwise);

// add listeners
suite
.on('cycle', function(event) {
    console.log(String(event.target));
})
.on('complete', function() {
    console.log('Fastest is ' + this.filter('fastest').map('name'));
})

// run async
.run({ 'async': false });


function testMathFloor()
{
    arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

function testNotBitwise()
{
    arr[~~(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

function testOrBitwise()
{
    arr[Math.random() * arr.length | 0];
}
```

Comment: Em ambientes modernos talvez seja menos "obscuro" utilizar o [`Math.trunc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc) ao invés do `~~`. De todo modo, ainda prefiro o `floor`, clássico nessa situação. Ainda vou comentar que performance não deve ser um fator muito decisivo em JS. Se for importante, tá na linguagem errada. :D

Comment: Performance no caso de ter muitas operações e não escolha de linguagem, não tem sentido escrever em C para navegadores, estou falando apenas de quantidade de operações.